# Change of variables for $p$-adic integral

Tags: measure-theory, integration, l-functions, p-adic-analysis, p-adic-numbers

Say $p$ is an odd prime. Suppose I have a measure $\mu$ on $\mathbf{Z}_p$. As in II.4.3 in [Colmez - Fonctions d'une variable $p$-adique](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~pierre.colmez/fonctionsdunevariable.pdf), I can restrict $\mu$ to $1+p\mathbf Z_p$, and there is a formula which tells me how to compute the Amice transform in terms of the original one in a simple way: $$\mathcal{A}_{\mathrm{Res}_{1+p\mathbf{Z}_p}(\mu)}(T) = \frac{1}{p} \sum_{\eta \in \mu_p} \eta^{-1} \mathcal{A}_\mu((1+T)\eta-1)$$

But suppose I define a new measure $\tilde{\mu}$ on $\mathbf{Z}_p$ by $$\int_{\mathbf{Z}_p} f(x) \cdot\tilde\mu(x) := \int_{1+p\mathbf{Z}_p}f(\log(x)/p)\cdot \mu(x)$$ which is by definition $$\int_{\mathbf{Z}_p} f(\log(x)/p) \mathbf{1}_{1+p\mathbf{Z}_p}(x)\cdot\mu(x)$$ and equal to $$\int_{\mathbf{Z}_p} f(\log(x)/p) \cdot \mathrm{Res}_{1+p\mathbf{Z}_p}(\mu)(x)$$
Then is there any way to get my hands on the Amice transform $\mathcal{A}_{\tilde{\mu}}$ in terms of $\mathcal{A}_\mu$, as above?

Comment: As a note, the Amice transform is defined on p. 30 of the linked paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the answer is probably not, since it would imply that the Iwasawa power series of a $p$-adic $L$-function has a "simple" relation with the original measure on $1+p\mathbb{Z}_p$. But the Iwasawa power series is usually hard to compute (explicitly). But, there are relations between your two measures, for example, under certain assumptions, the mu and lambda invariants of both measures are related. You may take a look at the following articles:

[Warren Sinnott, On the $\mu$-invariant of the $\Gamma$-transform of a rational function](https://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/toc/?PID=PPN356556735_0075)

[Yûji Kida, The $\lambda$-invariants of $p$-adic measures on ${\bf Z}_p$ and $1+q{\bf Z}_p$](https://kanazawa-u.repo.nii.ac.jp/?action=pages_view_main&active_action=repository_view_main_item_detail&item_id=11211&item_no=1&page_id=13&block_id=21)

[Nancy Childress, $\lambda$-invariants and $\Gamma$-transforms](https://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/toc/?PID=PPN365956996_0064)

[Junya Satoh, Iwasawa $\lambda$-invariants of $\Gamma$-transforms](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022314X92900865)

(Your question is from July, so this comment is late. It would be interesting to know how you solved this problem.)

Comment: Thanks! In the end I was very confused about something which led me to this computation, and it turns out I don't need it. But I appreciate the links.

Comment: @AshwinIyengar I’m trying to find explicitly the map of some distribution on weight space, and it led me to the exact same computations as in your post. May I ask what the purpose of your computations were, and how you managed to bypass the need for a change of variables formula? Thanks in advance!